# How to update Apexcharts data by using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, apexcharts

In our Application, we are displaying a chart and that needs to be updated constantly when a user-entered/changed input box value.

I call ajax to update charts data (series data) when the input value changed but chats disappeared after Ajax response.

I have the following code to update Chart's Data

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    
    const apexChart = "#chart_1";
    var options = {
        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [[0, 61.800509], [38.40001963, 61.16179846], [76.80003925, 60.52701894], [115.2000589, 59.89221522], [153.6000785, 59.25741165], [192.0000981, 58.62260808]]
        }],
        chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: 'line',
            offsetX: 1
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        stroke: {
            curve: 'straight',
            dashArray: [0, 0, 15, 5, 0]
        },
        xaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 4500,
            tickAmount: 9,
            type: 'numeric',
        },
        grid: {
            row: {
                colors: ['#f3f3f3', 'transparent'],
                opacity: 0.5
            },
        },
        colors: [primary, danger, '', '', '']
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector(apexChart), options);
    chart.render();

    //Call ajax when input value changed
    $.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + "{controller}/{method}",
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        //beforeSend: function() { openLoadingDialog('#container'); },
        success: function (response) {
            //closeLoadingDialog('#container');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            chart.updateSeries([{
                name: 'Speed',
                data: response
            }]);
        }
    });
});
```

When I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`, the output value is

```
"[[0.0,61.8],[38.4,61.2],[76.8,60.5],[115.2,59.9],[153.6,59.3],[192.0,58.6]]"
```

If I copy the response value and paste it in `updateSeries()`, then the chart loads fine.

Any help to update the chart's series data by Ajax?

Comment: Without seeing what `response` looks like, it's impossible to tell. Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` to your Ajax success handler and paste the output this generates into your question.

Comment: @Tomalak I have added console value to the question.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between "doing it by hand" and "doing it by Ajax". When you comment out `chart.updateSeries([{name: 'Speed', data: response}]);` in your success callback, and replace it with `chart.updateSeries([{name: 'Speed', data: [[0.0,61.8],[38.4,61.2],[76.8,60.5],[115.2,59.9],[153.6,59.3],[192.0,58.6]]}]);`  - does it work?

Comment: Yes, If I replace it with then it will work.

Comment: Then the obvious conclusion is that `response` does not *really* look like you expect it to. Undo all the commenting out, set a breakpoint on `chart.updateSeries([{name: 'Speed', data: response}]);`, and look at what `response` actually contains. There must be a difference.

Comment: It worked after I added response in JSON.parse(). like chart.updateSeries([{name: 'Speed', data: JSON.parse(response) }]); @Tomalak - Thank you very much for you help

Comment: If you add the `Content-Type: application/json` response header on your server, jQuery will recognize that and parse the JSON for you.

Comment: I Will try with that @Tomalak

Answer (score 2):

I got it working after I put a response in JSON.parse.

```
$.ajax({
        url: APP_URL + "{controller}/{method}",
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        //beforeSend: function() { openLoadingDialog('#container'); },
        success: function (response) {
            //closeLoadingDialog('#container');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            chart.updateSeries([{
                name: 'Speed',
                data: JSON.parse(response)
            }]);
        }
    });
```